# Use lodash to create array from object by property name

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that I need to turn into an array of data, based on a specific key.

**Here is my original object:**

```
{
  "centerID": "6",
  "marketID": "1",
  "invoiceGroupID": "4",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 7:00AM-11:00AM",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    }
  ],
  "bankedHoursYN": "N"
}
```

Currently, I am using `filter` to only provide me the `blocks` where `isChecked = true` by using `_.filter(this.mappingForm.get('blocks').value, { isChecked: true })`.

The result of this leaves me with:

```
{
  "centerID": "6",
  "marketID": "1",
  "invoiceGroupID": "4",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    }
  ],
  "bankedHoursYN": "N"
}
```

This works fine, leaving me with an array of two objects.

My end result is to just have an array of the `name` values.

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "centerID": "6",
  "marketID": "1",
  "invoiceGroupID": "4",
  "blocks": ['Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM','Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM'],
  "bankedHoursYN": "N"
}
```

Does lodash have a built in way to handle this?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @brk `"blocks": ['Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM','Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM'],`

Comment: i don't see difference between one and other

Comment: @Erubiel The original object has `blocks` which is an array of objects. I want that to only be an array of values (not contain `name` and `isChecked`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Why would you want lodash for the task? Javascript can do this with no extras needed.

Comment: @connexo - `lodash` is already being used elsewhere in this project for other things, was just checking to see if there were ways to do it in the library since it was already included.

Comment: @SBB I see, yet I don't think lodash is making things any easier here.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, please pick an answer. If not, please comment on the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `_.filter()`, and `_.map()` to get the just the names of the `blocks` with `isChecked: true`:

```js
const data = { "centerID": "6", "marketID": "1", "invoiceGroupID": "4", "blocks": [ { "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM", "isChecked": true }, { "name": "Monday-Friday 7:00AM-11:00AM", "isChecked": false }, { "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM", "isChecked":true } ], "bankedHoursYN": "N" };

data.blocks = _(data.blocks)
  .filter('isChecked')
  .map('name')
  .value();
  
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does lodash have a built in way to handle this?

I don't know, but Javascript has.

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` and chain `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
let obj = {
  "centerID": "6",
  "marketID": "1",
  "invoiceGroupID": "4",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 7:00AM-11:00AM",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    }
  ],
  "bankedHoursYN": "N"
}

obj.blocks = obj.blocks.filter(i=>i.isChecked).map(i=>i.name)

console.log(obj)
```

If you need to use ES5:

```
obj.blocks = obj.blocks
  .filter(function(i) { return i.isChecked })
  .map(function(i) { return i.name });
```

Answer (score 0):

After filtering the `blocks`, you can use `map` and `concat` to join the `name` of `block` object.

```js
var data = { "centerID": "6", "marketID": "1", "invoiceGroupID": "4", "blocks": [ { "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM", "isChecked": true }, { "name": "Monday-Friday 7:00AM-11:00AM", "isChecked": false }, { "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM", "isChecked":true } ], "bankedHoursYN": "N" };
data.blocks = _.chain(data.blocks).filter({ isChecked: true }).map(({name}) => name).concat().value();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for what built in functionality is there for performing `map` and `filter` together, then you can always combine `map` and `filter` operation in a single `reduce` (whether in `lodash` or in plain `vanilla JS`) to iterate the array only once.

So, the structure will be:

`<Array>.reduce((res, each) => (<filter condition> && res.push(<mapped data>), res), [])`

So, In your case: 
`obj.blocks.reduce((r, b) => (b.isChecked && r.push(b.name), r), [])`

```js
var obj = {
  "centerID": "6",
  "marketID": "1",
  "invoiceGroupID": "4",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 11:00AM-3:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Monday-Friday 7:00AM-11:00AM",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Saturday-Sunday 2:00PM-8:00PM",
      "isChecked": true
    }
  ],
  "bankedHoursYN": "N"
};

obj.blocks = obj.blocks.reduce((r, b) => (b.isChecked && r.push(b.name), r), []);

console.log(obj)
```

However, I will suggest you not to mutate and make a copy of your original object and override the `blocks` on the copy to make it a fresh output.

Answer (score 0):

var data.blocks = *.map(*.filter(data.blocks,function(o) { return o.isChecked===true; }),'name');